# mass rename of files with different prefixes in a folder

Tags: cmd, rename, file-management

[File names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIlpV.png)

In the above picture is an example of the file structure.

I have looked at many cmd lines for mass renaming but they all have either the same prefix or the same amount of characters.

Is there a way to rename multiple files with different prefixes but keep the text and file type. so 111 tiger.txt to tiger.txt and 32133_lion.txt to lion.txt.

Comment: You probably don't care for tool answers but https://www.1-4a.com/rename/ that tool would do it. (Long time since i used it, and couldn't find any way to regex it up; but advanced mode got many checkboxes at least!)

Comment: What is your plan for renaming when both `123dog.txt` and `124dog.txt` are in the same directory?

Comment: The folder that I will be renaming doesn't have any duplicates luckily.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy in PowerShell. The key is using a regex match to strip off the leading digits and '_' and space.

```
C:>type .\rd\doit.ps1
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

Get-ChildItem "C:\src\t\rd" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Name -match "\d*[_ ]*(.*)" | Out-Null

        if ($matches[1] -ne $null) {
            if ($_.Name -ne $matches[1]) {
                Rename-Item $_.FullName $matches[1] -WhatIf
            }
        }
    }
```

When you believe that correct renaming will be done, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
C:>.\rd\doit.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\123dog.txt Destination: C:\src\t\rd\dog.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\124cat.txt Destination: C:\src\t\rd\cat.txt".
```